# Jquery dialog echo check content

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

How to check echo dialog alert

if `<div class="mydialog"></div>` no dialog alert

else `<div class="mydialog"> $Value-content </div>` echo dialog alert $Value-content

Thanks

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'IF (' . $Value-content . ' != \"\")'
   ,     'Alert(' . $Value-content . ');'
   , '</script>'
   ;
```